# getting both event summary AND present status from ical using applescript or the terminal?

Tags: terminal, applescript, icalendar

I'm trying to query iCal to find out if an event in a specific calendar is occurring now, and if so, what the name of the event is—using either applescript or the terminal (I really don't know much about either). I saw a similar question about using applescript to retrieve the summary of *all* of the events of the current day, but that's not exactly what i'm looking for. ([Applescript and iCal interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928273/applescript-and-ical-interaction)).

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [filter form](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/reference/ASLR_reference_forms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH4g-BAJJHEFE):

```
tell application "iCal"
    get every event of calendar cal ¬
        where (start date ≤ (current date)) and (end date > (current date))
end tell
```

Note that `start date` and `end date` must come before `(current date)`, otherwise you'll get an error.

Comment: @Antal: it depends. I'll go with ≤ and >.